# Regex match everything within a parenthesis which does not have a closing parenthesis

Tags: regex, match

Can anyone help me find text which is within a parenthesis where the closing parenthesis is missing, so i can match the opening parenthesis and it's content without matching parenthesis which have a closing parenthesis.

```
George Peppard (John 'Hannibal' Smith), Dirk Benedict (Templeton 'Faceman' Peck), Dwight Schultz ('Howling Mad' Murdock), Mr T (B
```

So using regex i can find the content with the missing parenthesis and remove it along with the content in the parenthesis

Making it look like this below, sometimes the content within the missing parenthesis can be more than one character

```
George Peppard (John 'Hannibal' Smith), Dirk Benedict (Templeton 'Faceman' Peck), Dwight Schultz ('Howling Mad' Murdock), Mr T
```

Comment: What efforts have you put on solving it and what is the language or tool?

Comment: How is the end of the content inside the parentheses defined when the ending parenthesis is missing? This isn't a regular expression question, it is an attempt to square the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\([^)]*(?=,)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/137),,, in which tried match the `string content unclosed`.

And may remove it by `replacing` it with `nothing`.